# How to build .vdproj using MSBuild task?

Tags: msbuild, installation, projects-and-solutions

I get following error when I try the following command:

```
devenv.exe /build Debug SetupProject.vdproj
```

> ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.

Answer (score 0):

We use to build our Vdproject using devenv.exe. Devenv.exe will be wrapped into MSbuild exec task.

You can get reference from Msdn.

But your error is not relevant to msbuild problem